# Need some help doing a XML / XSLT transformation

Tags: html, xslt, transformation

I am using XSL-FO and FOP to generate PDFs. I am in the process of converting a complex HTML page to PDF.

I ran into the following error:

**Unknown formatting object "{}br" encountered (a child of p). (No context available)**

The FOP processor doesn't understand the format of the XSL-FO I am providing, because there are still some HTML tags in it. I would like to filter `<p>` and `<br/>` tags in the xml linked below:

http://www.tekstenuitleg.net/xmlinput.xml

In the last bits, under "Tab element 1" and "Tab element 2" you can see the `<p>` and `<br/>` that FOP doesn't understand.

Could you help me filter these out with XSLT and replace them with `<fo:block>some replacement here</fo:block>`? I tried a number of different XSLT stylesheets, but they don't quite work. I reverted the XSLT to what I had in the very beginning. The below XSLT doesn't fail, but doens't do any transforming either.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What should I add to this XSLT to replace the `<p>` and `<br>` tags in my source XML?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want to remove the physical P/BR tags but keep their contents.

In which case, see this XMLPlayground session (see XML in output source)

http://www.xmlplayground.com/9OE0NI

The iteration template does one of two things:

- if the current node is a P/BR, output only its contents, not the tag
- otherwise, output the tag and contents

...then recurse for child nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I solved the issue by adding the xsl-fo namespace to the xslt file and by changing your example to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a template for each element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="br">
        <!-- -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, this is the XSL I use to replace `<br>` and `<p>` tags. You need the xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format is you want to output XSLFO like `<fo:block>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select='*' />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='*'>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='name() = "p"'>
            <fo:block>
              <xsl:value-of select='.' />
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test='name() = "br"'>
             <fo:block></fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy select='.' />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates select='*' />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hm, I thought this worked, but I am actually missing a lot of the source XML when applying this XSLT. And the transformer doesn't accept the select attribute on the xsl:copy element...